# Methods inside model getting executed more than twice in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-routing

I have a Model, that i am call inside a Controller function. I am calling viewcategory function at page loads and calling some module function but why its getting executed 2-3 times ?

CategoryPost Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CategoryPost extends CI_Controller {

function viewcategory($name)
    {

    $this->load->database();

    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $this->load->model('categorypostmod');
    $this->load->model("site_model");

    $page = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $categCount = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorycount($name);

    $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/b3/index.php/CategoryPost/viewcategory/" . $name . "/page/";
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;

    log_message('info', 'count is ' . $categCount);

    $config['total_rows'] = $categCount;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';

    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = ' Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 5;

    $data['query'] = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorypost($name, $config['per_page'], $page);

  //  $records = $this->db->get('post', $config['per_page'], $page);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $this->load->view('script');
    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('cat_content_list', $data);

    $this->load->view('aside');
    $this->load->view('bottom');

    $this->load->model('Aside_mod');
    if($this->Aside_mod->check_cat_exists($name)){

        $this->Aside_mod->update_cat_count($name, $this->Aside_mod->get_cat_count($name)+1);
     }
     else{
            $this->Aside_mod->add_cat_views($name);
        }

    }//end function

}//end class
```

Model

```
class Aside_mod extends CI_Model {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

function save_cat($name){
if($this->check_cat_exists($name)){
$this->update_cat_count($name,$this->Aside_mod->get_cat_count($name)+1);
}
else{
$this->add_cat_views($name);
    }
}

function getpopular_categ(){
$this->db->select('tags');
$this->db->from('post');
return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

function add_cat_views($name){
$data = array(
           'tagname' => $name,
           'count' =>0

        );

return $this->db->insert('tagcount', $data); 
}

function update_cat_count($name,$countval){
$data = array(       
           'count' =>$countval
              );
$this->db->where('tagname', $name);
$this->db->update('tagcount', $data); 
}   

function check_cat_exists($name){
$exist=false;
$this->db->select('tagname');
$this->db->where('tagname',$name);

$query = $this->db->get('tagcount');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
log_message('info', 'Exists ');
$exist=true;
}
return $exist;
}

function get_cat_count($name){
$this->db->where('tagname',$name);
$query=$this->db->get('tagcount');
$co=0;
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){ 
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
$co= $row->count;
}
}
return $co;
}

function getCategorypost($catname,$lim1,$lim2){ 
$this->db->cache_on();
$this->db->select('*')->from('post')->like('post.tags',$catname)->limit($lim1, $lim2);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Only going by what you have provided so far... Looking at your controller- you are calling the model 2-3 times depending upon the result of your IF statement near the end!

So it's doing what you are telling it to do!

It would make more sense to refactor your Controller so you just make a single call to the model and have all that if,else code performed in the model.

So in your Model - create a new method to contain the code ( as a first iteration and could be refined)

```
public function save_cat($name)
{
  if($this->check_cat_exists($name)) {
    $this->update_cat_count($name, $this->get_cat_count($name)+1);
  }
  else {
    $this->add_cat_views($name);
  }
}
```

Then your controller becomes...

```
<snip>
        $this->load->view('aside');
        $this->load->view('bottom');

        $this->load->model('aside_mod');
        $this->aside_mod->save_cat($name);
      }//end function

    }//end class
```

Comment: How are you seeing it being "executed"?  Are you calling the controller/method from other places?

Comment: I have a database and count value is one here , so after i gets updated its value is 3 , as in my case it should be 2 .. shall i git my app , so that you can understand better ??

Comment: @Sanjay-Dev If you would like to, sure!